# Where to put model "utility" functions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with several models.

I have a function that I want to access from several models.

What's the best place to put this code and how can I make it accessible from the models that need to get at it?

My understanding is that helpers are just for views.  Is this correct?

It seems wrong to create a plug-in and put it in the vendor folder - this is my code and integral to my app. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create a module under lib and mix this into the models that need it, for instance, in lib/fooable.rb:

```
module Fooable
  def do_foo
  end
end
```

And then in your various models:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Fooable
end
```

No need to require fooable.rb, the Rails autoloading mechanism will find it for you as long as it's named using correct conventions.

Comment: Rails 4: including didn't work for me, but requiring did. I also had to call the function like this: Fooable.function

Comment: @smilingcow It's the matter of configuraton since `rails 3`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5273470/535406) answer for details.

Comment: Things like this I put in /model/concerns (if it's only to extend models) but for utility classes I put them in lib/utils (lib can get crowded)

Comment: Why this is better than service object? I keep bumping onto that topic.

Comment: @mlt it is neither better or worse than a service object. If you start to have multiple "utility" methods that seem to have something in common there might be a refactoring opportunity to extract a new class.

Answer (score 1):

In order to lessen the repetition of code, you could also create a main class which would include that module and the simply inherit from it from every model you'd like to share the behaviour.

Something like:

```
module Fooable
  def do_foo
  end
end

class ParentModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Fooable
end

class Product < ParentModel end
class User < ParentModel end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base end
```

Thus, in that example, both Product and User would share the do_foo functionality and Item would not.

Comment: This works of course, but I would question whether eliminating the repetition is worth dirtying the inheritance chain; you could argue that this is exactly what modules help avoid: unnecessary inheritance. Is trying to avoid multiple include statements taking DRY one step too far? I think it might be.

Comment: This will also cause problems when your ParentModel has a string column called "type" in the database, as this will cause [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) to kick in.