# lib directory is not looked in by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I following [Ryan's subdomain railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) where het creates a Subdomain class used in his routes and places it in the lib directory. Apparantly my rails app isn't looking in the lib dir by default (my app only starts when I move the subdomain.rb file from lib to eg /app/models)

I always thought that the lib dir was included by default in a rails app? How can I best include this directory to make this happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 does not autoload it by default (although Rails 2 does).  You have to add it to your autoload_paths in application.rb.

```
module YourRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
    #...
  end
end
```

For more info on the reason behind this see:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5218-rails-3-rc-does-not-autoload-from-lib

Comment: That URL is not a public URL.