# Where to put model “utility” functions in Ruby on Rails, if it is also required in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

This is a 2nd part to the following question:

[Where to put model "utility" functions in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242533/where-to-put-model-utility-functions-in-ruby-on-rails)

Problem is, I need access to these utility functions from a rake task as well. Using the accepted technique in in the other thread, I get an "undefined method" error when accessing my model from a rake task.

What is the best way to fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to define your rake task as dependent on the Rails environment:

```
task :my_task => :environment do
  # Will load Rails stack before executing this block

  MyModel.foo
end
```

The default behavior is to load almost nothing, so you won't have access to your models unless you ask for it.

Comment: This gives me access to my models yes. But not to a module used in my models, if that modules lives in a file under lib/

Comment: If that's the case, you do this in your rake file: `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/my_file.rb`.

Comment: It turns out my problems were due to my confusion between include/extend. @tadman, I suppose your answer is correct, (although it wasn't my problem). Thanks all.