# Rails 3.2 - Where do "utility" functions get saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to put logic related to the creation/modification/deletion of objects in files outside of those objects associated controllers. For instance, I want to call on a "create_event" method from User but I do not want to do "Event.create()" because there's all sorts of logic involved that does not belong in the model. Where do these files go? In lib? Would this be any different in Rails 4?

This same question was asked in 2009 ([Where to put model "utility" functions in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242533/where-to-put-model-utility-functions-in-ruby-on-rails)) but since that was four years ago, I wanted to be sure it was still correct.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't create an `EventManger` class and put it in `app/models`? Your models are your business logic. That's where the vast majority of your program should reside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is almost a year old, I want to revisit it in case anyone else stumbles upon it. After a lot of consideration, I ended up making service classes that sit between certain models and controllers for the purpose of processing complex forms and relationships. This is similar to the [EAA : service layer pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) linked above and heavily influenced by Ryan Bates, as recommended in [RailsCasts episode 398](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects?view=comments). In the video, Ryan's exact words are, "Service Objects work best for complex controller actions that need to interact with a complex model and where there’s no other good place for that behaviour," and this described my needs perfectly.

I was VERY green when posing my initial question, so it wasn't really phrased as well as it could have been. I feel like it comes across as wanting to take basic behavior away from models, which wasn't the case. I'll elaborate in case anyone else who's new Rails and/or OOP stumbles upon this and knows what they want to accomplish but not exactly how.

In my case, I'm using Neo4j, so the relationships between objects are objects themselves. When dealing with complex associations ("an event has three bands and a venue, the form may be submitted with any combination of new and existing bands and a venue plus unique data that needs to be associated with either the band/venue objects or the relationships between them and the event... and it's all coming through the Events controller") I kept finding myself in these gray areas where responsibility for a task was questionable. Is it the event's job to set the unique band description for a specific event? Rails would say it is. It would have me send my params to Event, then Event would reach out to Band and Venue... but why is that Event's job? Why should Event be responsible for so much back and forth with other objects?

Furthermore, when something broke, it sometimes became Where's Waldo for finding the offending code. Is it the Event model? The Band model? Again, who owns the overall process of connecting the dots? They are shared responsibilities. At the end of the day, models are the gatekeepers to the objects and control their behavior, but what are the gatekeepers for the shared information between the models?

Service objects as implemented by Ryan Bates in his webcast were my salvation. The Events controller sends form data to the EventManager class. EventManager pulls apart the form, sends pieces of it to other specialized service classes -- VenueManager and BandManager -- and they validate the data, then work with their associated models to perform queries and/or create new objects when necessary. The secondary service classes return objects and boolean responses to EventManager, then EventManager sets relationship properties as needed. My behavior is isolated and easier to test, read, and expand.

Since the management classes are objects with responsibilities, I include `ActiveModel::Validations` in each one. Errors bubble up and I can feel safe that it will bail on a process if it runs into trouble.

Anyone looking for advice on Ruby OOP should read [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321721330) by Sandi Metz. It's really a joy to read and perfect for people who need to break some bad habits picked up from being self-taught, or just want to consider better ways of organizing their code. Basic OOP concepts made it clear to me that the responsibility of my management objects needed to be handled separately from my Rails models.

Answer (score 2):

The lib directory is usually used for logic that's not associated with your app, i.e. you can reuse in another project. You can think of it as a directory where you put logic that should be a gem, but it's still not.

As @meagar said, an `EventManager` is a good approach, since this code will live with the rest of the application logic. An alternative would be to create an `EventModule` (in `app/modules`) that will contain helper methods when dealing with events.

Answer (score 0):

lib is definitely not suited for that. As alfonso said, it's for classes that you can reuse accross differents applications. Like a pdf generator or so.

Models in Rails are used for persistance and business logic, but when this business logic involves multiple it's getting more difficult. Personally I like to use a service layer between controllers and models for that kind of needs.

I just create a folder beside controllers, models and views that contains classes like EventService.

[EAA : Service layer pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)

**Rails 4**

It does not change with Rails 4